# Handling messages with actors

Tags: scala, akka, message

I have 2 actors, actor A send messages to actor B. Actor B then should process these numbers and print them on the same line

My code:

```
class ActorB extends Actor{
  def receive = {
     case 0 => println("0")
     case x : Int => println (x)
  }
}
```

but won't compile

Comment: If you are going to make your actor stateful anyway, why not just store messages in a local list and then print them out whenever your list contains 3 items?

Comment: I added an answer. Stateful means that your value (your actor) will behave different as "time" goes by, i.e., your actor does not perform the same action every time he receives a message if you use become/unbecome. In my answer below, you limit the statefulness to the list contained by your actor, looking at the receive case it is a bit clearer what is going on because we handle the state of the list in a way that is readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this (totally untested):

```
class ActorB extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  def receive = {
    case x : Int => context.become(waitingForMore(List(x)))
  }

  def waitingForMore(xs : List[Int]) : Receive = {
    case x : Int if(xs.size == 2) => 
      printResults(x :: xs)
      context.become(receive)

    case x : Int => context.become(waitingForMore(x :: xs))    
  }

  def printResults(xs : List[Int]): Unit = {
    // Do printing here.
  }
}
```

In this model, you would take advantage of the fact that Actors can alter their own internal behavior. You wouldn't be explicitly storing a list of Ints, but instead you would be passing it from function to function. Essentially the actor waits around for you to send it an Int (the `receive` method) and then enters a state where it gathers more results (the `waitingForMore` method). Once that method has gathered enough, it prints the results and returns back into the `receive` method, which starts the process all over again.

*Edit* As suggested, I'll just add a small comment as to why I proposed this model. I feel like the state your actor is in is more clearly modeled with this. As the problem grows and gets more complicated, this might be a good pattern to have in your head. Or it might not, as Felix pointed out both of these solutions get to the same answer through different ways. You should absolutely feel free to pick whichever solution you feel more comfortable with. My intent in showing this was to demonstrate an alternate approach that is more functional, that's all.

Comment: The problem IMHO is that we don't seem to gain anything here compared to my solution. It is not more functional as we are changing the implementation of "receive". It is not easier to read either. Maybe you could elaborate on when you would use this instead of explicitly managing state internally?

Comment: Agreed that both implementations get to the same result at the end of the day. With that in mind OP should chose whichever one he/she feels will get the job done for them. I'm not sure I'd even implement it this way (I'd probably explicitly model state, as you have it) but I was just proposing an alternate solution that I've seen work before.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```scala
class ActorB extends Actor with ActorLogging{
  var xs:List[Int] = Nil
  def receive = {
     case x : Int => 
        xs = x :: xs
        if(xs.length==3){
           println(xs.mkString(" ")+" avg: "+xs.sum/3d)
           xs = Nil
        }
  }
}
```

(I didn't test the above, but it should give you the idea)

I think this may be a bit easier than to use become/unbecome. Is there a reason you want to use that pattern instead maybe?

Comment: I'm not on acomputer with Scala installed right now, but I think you should be able to debug this yourself maybe :)

Comment: You can just reverse the list when you print it, e.g. println(xs.reverse.mkString(" ")+" avg: "+xs.sum/3d). The logic is quite simple. You save each message you get to the front of the list 'xs'. If, after saving the current element, your list has size 3, you simply print it out and define xs to be a new empty list.